# How to query TFS for the "x" most recent iterations, for charting purposes?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a TFS query that pulls in data from recent sprints, in order to display a chart on our dashboard. However, [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/charts?view=vsts):

> When a chart contains more than seven items within the data series, values in the eight-plus items are consolidated into a set labeled "other"

This is exactly what happens with us. The first few Iterations on the chart are static, and as every Iteration passes by, the "Other" row increases.

How can I alter my query to only pull in the last seven iterations? I can't do something like `Iteration ID >= @Current Iteration - 6` because `@Current Iteration` is supported only for `Iteration Path`, not `Iteration ID`.

Comment: Which one are you actually using? It contains both tags tfs & vsts in your question.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFTI'm using VSTS. I commented on your answer below, it might be in the right direction, but we're not quite there yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to achieve this through in TFS for now.

However for VSTS, it's added now.

> The deployment of this feature to all VSTS accounts is now complete.
>   You can find full details in our Release Notes
>   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2018/mar-05-vsts#query-work-across-the-iteration-schedule-with---currentiteration).
>
> TFS customers can look forward to the feature **in a future feature
>   update**.
>
> *[Source Link](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13314216-vso-support-currentiteration-1-for-next-or-past)*

### Query work across the iteration schedule with +/- @CurrentIteration

The @CurrentIteration macro that helps your team track work based on your iteration schedule now supports integer offset. Easily keep tabs on the work that didn’t get closed with @CurrentIteration - 1, or look ahead at the work planned for future iterations with @CurrentIteration + 1. See the [**@CurrentIteration post**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/03/01/currentiteration-team-parameter-offset/) on the Microsoft DevOps Blog for more information.

***Update:***

[image]

Logical expression: Work Item Type = any And State= any AND (Iteration= CurrentIteration OR Iteration= CurrentIteration-1 OR...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I wrote in the original post, I can't use `@CurrentIteration - x` as it doesn't work with `Iteration ID`. I tried using it with `Iteration Path`, but I still can't find the magic formula for "all iterations between `@CurrentIteration and @CurrentIteration - 6`. Do you know how I could express that in a query?

Comment: You could just use Iteration Path to get “x” most recent iterations, we do not use Iteration ID for this purpose.  Take a look at this blog: [Define iteration paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=vsts) You could use [Group clauses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries?view=vsts&tabs=new-query-exp#group-clauses) to handle this, I also add a update screenshot in my original reply for your reference.

Comment: Thanks, worked great. Shame I can't do something like `Iteration Path >= @Current Iteration - 6` as it's a bit messy, but it did work.